# Insertar Emojis en base de datos SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Buen día,

Tengo una inquietud y la verdad es que no se como insertar emojis en base de datos SQL Server y además poder hacer una consulta a este tipo de campo.

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a imagenes o emojis de unicode?

Comment: los emojis son texto que es parseado por quien lo muestra de forma de ver un dibujito.. solo tenes que guardar el texto...}

Answer (score 0):

La tabla tiene que estar creada y soportar UTF-8 para eso, algo así:

```
CREATE TABLE tabla(columna VARCHAR(250) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8);
```

Luego puedes insertar en la columna de una tabla específica el emoji que requieres anteponiendo el `string N`:

```
INSERT INTO tabla(columna) VALUES (N'⚙');
```

Y ya está, luego haz una consulta a la tabla y verifica que esté el emoji.

> Te recomiendo leer los siguientes enlaces:
>
> - [Add emoji / emoticon to SQL Server table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33938445/add-emoji-emoticon-to-sql-server-table)
> - [Introducing UTF-8 support for SQL Server](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/introducing-utf-8-support-for-sql-server/ba-p/734928)

Comment: Esta respuesta requiere una versión reciente de SQL Server. Para versiones anteriores es mejor utilizar el tipo de dato NVARCHAR y se evita la necesitad de cambiar la intercalación (collation)